# USB DAC in 13.04 does not appear in Settings or lsusb

Tags: sound, usb

I'm using a Schiit Audio Modi USB DAC on 13.04. I had it working in the past, it occasionally did not show up in Settings>Sound. This was always fixed by uninstalling and reinstalling alsa-utils. The last time I tried to do that, my computer froze and I was forced to hard reboot. After this, reinstalling alsa-utils did not fix the issue. My DAC does not show up if I use lsusb, it returns the following.

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Another thread suggested posting the output of `dmesg | tail`

```
[  595.499347] usb 1-4: Product: Schiit USB Audio Device
[  595.499353] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Schiit
[  595.530201] usbhid 1-4:1.2: can't add hid device: -71
[  595.530223] usbhid: probe of 1-4:1.2 failed with error -71
[  595.530325] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 34
[  595.768069] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 35 using ehci-pci
[  595.907322] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0d8c, idProduct=1319
[  595.907330] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  595.907336] usb 1-4: Product: Schiit USB Audio Device
[  595.907341] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Schiit
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to test.

1. Unplug the USB DAC
2. Swich to root `sudo su`
3. Run:

   ```
   clear ; modprobe -r usbhid ; echo "Plug now your USB DAC then wait" ; sleep 60 ; modprobe usbhid ; echo "Timeout Now, Test your DAC" ;
   ```

What gonna happen:

- usbhid will unloaded from kernel and your USB mouse and keyboard stop working.
- A message on terminal showed to you "Plug now your USB DAC then wait". So you plug your USB DAC before *60sec* delay pass.
- Wait till a message appear "Timeout Now, Test your DAC", usbhid will reloaded and your USB mouse and keyboard will back working. Then test you DAC.

Worst things may happen like mouse did not come back:

- If your keyboard is still working:

  Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>,  login, run `sudo modprobe usbhid`
- Otherwise, reboot.